# How can i fix MVC Parser error in asax file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a website almost 2 weeks and everything was fine. After 2 days break, i have an error about parsing. I was trying to run my codes and it showed me an error.

**Error is:**

> Satır 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="SeyahatSitesi.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

I checked the asax file, the names are okay. What is the problem?

**Global.asax.cs file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SeyahatSitesi
{
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

}

**Global.asax file**

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="SeyahatSitesi.MvcApplication.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Comment: can you show your Global.asax.cs including it's namespace.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace SeyahatSitesi
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Did you intend to rename Global to MvcApplication? Don't put the global asax code here in the comment. Include it in your post, update it.

Comment: Okay i did, you can look now

Answer (score 0):

The `Inherits` is incorrect, check below correct Inherits

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="SeyahatSitesi.MvcApplication.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Comment: I did but it's not working. Still same error.

Comment: There is no `SeyahatSitesi.MvcApplication.Global`. The "Inherits" class is `SeyahatSitesi.MvcApplication`.